# How to animate a low poly character with a cape?

Tags: modeling, animation, cloth-simulation

I modeled a low poly Batman with a cape, what I'd like to do now is to make a very basic rig and make it move.

My only problem is the cape: I'd like to have the cape move and not be completely rigid as it is now.

Is there any way I could do this?

I did try to use the cloth simulation, but I always get very strange results, probably because of my mesh.

[Here](https://mega.nz/file/IlMxEKrT#MujryARR9Nysrh0crYsZijRpAsKzJZ03V33O_c__vcc) you can find my blend file.

Comment: From you file, we can not deduce anything: there is no animation at all. So what is your concrete issue with the cape?

Comment: I do not know much about cloth sims, but I do know that BlenderGuru has a video on it and what all the settings do. May want to look at that. Otherwise, I suggest subdividing your mesh. Maybe it acts weird because it doesn't have enough vertices to move it nicely?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I usually do now for capes:

1. Create a simple **cape** using a plane with 16 vertices (4x4).
2. Parent the cape to an *Armature* (with *Empty Groups*).
3. Manually parent each vertex to each *Bone* in *Weight Paint Mode*.
4. Then add a *Subdivision Surface Modifier* AFTER the *Armature Modifier* in the stack for smooth deformation.
5. Make sure the cape has *Smooth* shading.

**Bonus** - Realistic wind animation:

- Animate your bones into a "cape down", "cape up", and then "cape down" pose.
- Offset each column of bones on the timeline. What I mean is, each column of bones consists of each group of four bones that run down the length of the cape. By offsetting, I mean move each column of four bones maybe a couple frames from each other in the Dope Sheet (staggering the animation helps simulate realistic wind movement).
- Add some *Cycles Modifiers* in the "Graph Editor" so it will loop.

**Double Bonus**: Use *NLA Strips* to store (and mix) different cape effects that you've preanimated.

[image]

Hope this helps any passersby! :) Peace and God bless!